# Loading code from a different html file

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a website with a news feed that I updated regularly. The problem is that when I update it I have to change the code in every page. This wouldn't be a problem if the website was small, but it has about 20 pages
I want to know if there is any way for me to just have a separate html file with just the newsfeed, that I would load on the other pages.

Comment: Is your website purely HTML? Any managed code behind the scenes?

Comment: Although you haven't shown any code, you could simply use an `iframe` to pull in an html file on the server, or use a language like PHP or ASP to `include` a file. Here's a start: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: You could load a static html file using AJAX.  Slightly excessive for your needs but it would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery and making an AJAX call would be one solution to your problem, although it's a bit excessive.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $.ajax({
                    url: "news.html",
                    cache: false
                }).done(function(news) {
                    $("#news").html(news);
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="news">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Another solution would be to simply use an iFrame.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="news">
            <iframe src="news.html"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to html :) I decided to use Iframe